# Приведение map к map

Tags: map, c++

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
unordered_map<int, shared_ptr<B> >  bs;
```

Как привести `bs` к `unordered_map<int, shared_ptr<A> >`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак, это невозможно нормальными средствами.

Действительно, представьте себе, что это было бы возможно:

```
unordered_map<int, shared_ptr<B> > bs;
unordered_map<int, shared_ptr<A> > as =
           some_special_cast< unordered_map<int, shared_ptr<A> > >(bs);
```

Тогда вы смогли бы *добавить* экземпляр класса `A` в `as` (`shared_ptr<A> pa(new A()); as[0] = pa;`). То есть и в `bs`! А это получиться не имеет права.

Вы *можете* попробовать `reinterpret_cast`, но это очень уж низкоуровневый хак.

---

Вот ещё по теме: [C++ FAQ/21.3](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/parkinglot-of-car-vs-vehicle.html).

---

В .NET есть так называемые *ковариантные* интерфейсы: имея контейнер объектов порождённого класса, вы можете получить read-only view на него как на контейнер элементов базового класса. Но в C++ такого нет.

---

Скорее всего, вашу проблему можно решить с помощью шаблонов. Расскажите о вашей *настоящей* задаче.